# Is this what a broken shear pin on a snowblower looks like?

Tags: engine, shear

I have a snowblower and [believe I have broken one of the shear pins](https://youtube.com/shorts/uH-fxKu3SHE?feature=share). In that YouTube video, you can see the first two blades won't budge or spin at all, and neither will the 4th.

But the 3rd blade spins freely. I'm guessing that's a broken shear pin?

Comment: Yep, broken shear pin or a bolt has fallen out.  The problematic piece should be fairly obvious.

Comment: And please be careful fixing it!

Comment: Yep. Engine off when fixing. On Cubs they have pin that slides through with a small pin to keep in place. Much easier than the other requiring lock nuts and spanners